# EF 6, How to delete an Entity without enforcing cascade delete and satisfying Foreign Key restraints

Tags: entity-framework, cascading-deletes

I'm trying to figure out how to delete an entity without cascade delete

I'm assuming if i do this right, when i delete a related entity (Country, see below), it will set the Country FK in Client to null and the world is all good

**Error**

```
The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.Clients_dbo.Countries_CountryId". The conflict occurred in database "JCE", table "dbo.Clients", column 'CountryId'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

---

The code i'm using

```
public class Country : IEntity
{
    [Required,Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required,Index]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class Client : IEntity
{

    [Required,Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

}
```

I use the following model builder

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
    .HasRequired(r => r.Country)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

And use the following code to delete a country

```
Db.Countries.Attach(country);
Db.Countries.Remove(country);
Db.SaveChanges();
```

---

**Question**

What do i need to do to satisfy my requirements?
Also Please let me know if you see any redundancies or oddities with the code i'm using thanks

Comment: This is worth a read: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/06/02/deleting-orphans-with-entity-framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `FK` constraint optional.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
    .HasOptional(r => r.Country)
    .WithMany()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

That way it is possible to have a nullable `Foreign key`.

Your `FK` will only be set to null if, and only if, your child object is also loaded in EF. So here you have to include your `Country` entity in when you retrieve your `Client` entity.

Comment: *head slap*, i'm not sure what part of HasRequired i didn't understand

Comment: @Saruman I guess the `Required` part. :) No, it can happen to anyone. Also, check my edit.

Comment: Ahh ok, so with the above configuration i.e (having no navigation to clients in country), what should i do?

Comment: Ok after Testing this works fine, as you say i need to have the child objects loaded for its fk to be set to null, Thanks